# How do I access libraries of my library projects in .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**ASP.NET Framework 4.7**

I have some `Class Libraries` in my project. And one of them has `my nuget package`.

For example :

`A Class Library` project has `NugetPackage1`

`B Class Library` has `A` as reference.

How can i get `NugetPackage1`'s classes in `B Class Library` ?

I created my nuget package my own by using this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>...</id>
    ...
    ...
  </metadata>
  <files>  
   <file src="Release\My.Nuget.Package.dll" target="lib\net47"></file>
  </files>
</package>

<!-- There have been created a nuget package. -->
<!-- lib\net47 folder is empty. Is this true ? -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s actually all there, built into NuGet/Visual Studio.

1-Select the solution in solution explorer
2-Right mouse click and select Manage NuGet Packages for solution…
3-Select Installed packages
4-Locate the package that’s already installed
5-Click the Manager button
6-Now simply locate your new project and tick the checkbox next
7-Click OK.

for more details see this: http://putridparrot.com/blog/how-to-reference-an-existing-nuget-package-from-a-new-project/

Comment: Actually, I was using .NET Core and it was so simple to use by not adding a nuget package to all projects. But in ASP.NET Framework, you are correct.